# How to add shadow to NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsshadow

I've spent some time trying to figure out how to add a shadow to an `NSView`. For now, I am attempting to use the `NSShadow` class to accomplish this. My code is below. I am attempting to create the shadow in a custom init method in a `NSView` subclass. No matter what I try, no shadow appears.

```
NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor blackColor]];

[self setWantsLayer:YES];
[self setShadow:dropShadow];
```

**Edit**

Here is how I tried to do it with `CALayer`.

```
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
self.layer.shadowPath = [self quartzPathFromBezierPath:[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:frame]];
```

`quartzPathFromBezierPath:` converts an `NSBezierPath` to a `CGPath`.

Comment: Have you tried View Effects Inspector in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 5):

use this with offset and other params need to be set

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
    NSShadow *dropShadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    [dropShadow setShadowColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [dropShadow setShadowOffset:NSMakeSize(0, -10.0)];
    [dropShadow setShadowBlurRadius:10.0];

    [self setWantsLayer: YES];
    [self setShadow: dropShadow];

    [dropShadow release];
}

return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `NSShadow` is to get the views layer and use its shadow related properties. In particular, be sure to set the `shadowOpacity` to something above 0 (the default).

Note that you can't use the shadow offset and the shadow path at the same time.

Comment: Check what `quartzPathFromBezierPath` returns, why don't you just ask the bezier for its path?

Comment: I don't think you can ask an `NSBezierPath` directly for a `CGPath` (even though you can for `UIBezierPath`). I found the source code for `quartzPathFromBezierPath:` on Apple's site. How would you do this though?

Comment: Ok, I misread the class name. Are you setting the view or layer to clip to bounds?

Answer (score 0):

Try following this answer, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859617/how-to-display-shadow-for-nsview/32882755)

I think the most important line is the `self.view.superview?.wantsLayer = true`