# Glow effect around NSView

Tags: swift, nsview, macos-sierra

Lots of examples on how to do create a glow effect on iOS UIView, but how do you do it on macOS? Preferably in Swift.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little vague (in particular, what is a "glow effect"?), but what I think you mean is a shadow effect with a light colour instead of a dark colour.

For this, you merely have to configure the NSView layer's `shadow` property, as per the documentation at:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1483263-shadow

Give the shadow a (0,0) offset to centre it behind the view, give it a decent radius around the edge of the view, and give it a light glowing colour, and appropriate opacity.

Complete code example is at:  [How to display shadow for NSView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859617/how-to-display-shadow-for-nsview)

If shadow is not what you're after, you may need to edit your question and elaborate on what you mean.

Comment: I second this, and further, any glow effect you find in iOS that uses Core Animation can fairly easily be adopted to OSX -- there are some extra steps you need to do, like set up the layer, and compensate for the flipped y-axis, but these should be fairly well documented.